# OpenVPN tunnel, iptables don't support NAT

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

I wanted to route my private PCs traffic through my VPS and set up my OpenVPN as fas as necessary but now I have the problem that I can't set iptables, since NAT support is disabled for my server's kernel. The command I would have used is

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0:0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now is there a way to implement the behaviour without NAT iptables rules?

Comment: Depending on the traffic you're trying to push, maybe Squid?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you don't have the necessary modules loaded, try loading them with

> modprobe nf_nat
>
> modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE

If this doesn't work it shouldn't be terribly difficult to recompile your kernel with support for nat